# Simplify set expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to simplify this expression:  (A ⋂ (B ⋃ C)') ⋂ (B ⋂  (A ⋃ C)') ⋂  (C ⋂  ( (A ⋃ B)')

The original equation was (A - (B ⋃ C)) ⋂ (B -(A ⋃ C)) ⋂  (C - (A ⋃ B))

I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: You did nothing except use different notation.  Get to work using  DeMorgan and distributive laws.

Answer (score 1):

there is a problem in the parenthesis of your first expression -- trying to fix it

(A ⋂ not(B ⋃ C)) ⋂ (B ⋂ not(A ⋃ C)) ⋂ (C ⋂  not(A ⋃ B))

empty set!

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28A+%E2%8B%82+not%28B+%E2%8B%83+C%29%29+%E2%8B%82+%28B+%E2%8B%82+not%28A+%E2%8B%83+C%29%29+%E2%8B%82+%28C+%E2%8B%82++not%28A+%E2%8B%83+B%29%29

[image: empty set]

[image]

Comment: yes, it is an empty set. however, our assignment entailed us to simplify the whole expression even if the regions are empty.

Answer (score 1):

After apply De Morgan's law gives
$$A\cap B'\cap C'\cap B\cap A'\cap C'\cap C\cap A'\cap B'$$
Use Commutative law to combine either $A\cap A',B\cap B'$ or $C\cap C'$, then by Complement Law that $$\varnothing\cap\dots$$
Now by Domination Laws the whole expression simplify to $\varnothing$.